# What library to link for glGetShaderiv?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to link an OpenGL 3 program on Windows 7 64 and the linker (gcc 4.7.0) doesn't find glGetShaderiv and glDeleteShader. Which library do I have to link for that?

Comment: You should read the ["Getting Started" page on the OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started).

Comment: I have -lopengl32 already in my linker settings.

Comment: Putting `-lopengl32` in your linker settings is not the same as reading and following the instructions given in that page. You have to do *everything* in the "Writing an OpenGL Application" section.

Answer (score 4):

Windows doesn't support any core OpenGL functions that are above version 1.1. You could a library like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to access those methods as if they were core methods.

Comment: GLee works fine for me, so it is not "defunct". It may not be up to date, but I clearly stated that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not actually that hostile. Still, why do you think it's defunct?